# Get position of element in listview when TextWatcher triggers

Tags: java, android

I'm having problems to get the position of my View inside a ListView when TextWatcher triggers for changes in EditText.

Each CardView has two EditTexts and two Spinners. When I make some change in the values for the name of the product (the EditText in the left) and for the spinners, my code get the correctly the position of the CardView in the list.

[image: The list described. my Toast should print "posicao = 0", because I've just changed the first element. However, it prints the last iterated value of the variable posicao. In this case, the last element.]

However, when I change the value of the price by typing it, my code cannot get it's position.
The position of the CardView is gotten in the line...

- **final int posicao = Integer.parseInt(consumableInfo.getName())**, which consumableInfo is the class listed in my Adapater, and consumableInfo.getName gets the name of the card, which is equal to the position of the card. Like "0", "1", "2"...

This happens because everytime I call...

- **holder.mAutoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener** for the AutoCompleteEditText on the left;
- **holder.mDivideConsumableSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener** for each spinner;

...my code iterates again over BindData. However, when I call...

- **holder.mConsumablePriceTextView.addTextChangedListener(priceTextWatcher)** for the EditText on the right;

... my code DO NOT iterates again.

I'm trying to find another way to get it's position, but I'm having problems with that. Maybe forcing a way to **posicao** get the value, or creating a customTextWatcher that implements TextWatcher and gets consumableInfo as a parameter.

```
public class ConsumableAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ConsumableAdapter.ConsumableViewHolder> {
/*...some code ommited...*/
int posicaoGlobal;

public ConsumableAdapter(Context context, List<ConsumableInfo> contactList) {...}/*...some code ommited...*/
}

public class ConsumableViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public AutoCompleteTextView mAutoCompleteTextView;
    public Spinner mDivideConsumableSpinner;
    public Spinner mUnitsConsumableSpinner;
    public EditText mConsumablePriceTextView;

    public ConsumableViewHolder(View itemView) {
       /*...*/
    }


    public void bindData(ConsumableInfo consumableInfo, ConsumableViewHolder holder, Context context) {

        final int posicao = Integer.parseInt(consumableInfo.getName());
        posicaoGlobal = posicao;

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(mContext, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,
                Constants.CONSUMABLE_CONSTANTS);
        holder.mAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);

        /* position is updated withmAutoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener */
        holder.mAutoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener({
                    updateTotalPrice(posicao);
                    /*...*/
        });


                    /*position is NOT updated with addTextChangedListener*/
   holder.mConsumablePriceTextView.addTextChangedListener(priceTextWatcher);



                    /*position is updated with setOnItemSelectedListener in both Spinners*/ 
        holder.mDivideConsumableSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    updateTotalPrice(posicao);
                    /*...*/
        });
        //product units
        holder.mUnitsConsumableSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    updateTotalPrice(posicao);
                    /*...*/
        });

    }

    private void updateTotalPrice(int posicao) {

       /*...*/
        mTotalPrice = getTotalPrice(BotequimActivity.mProductList, mPercent);
        BotequimActivity.mTotalPriceTextView.setText(getTotalPriceString());
        FormatStringAndText.setPriceTextViewSize(mTotalPrice, BotequimActivity.mTotalPriceTextView);
    }

}

private void updateTotalPrice(int posicao, String priceString) {
    /*...*/
    BotequimActivity.mTotalPriceTextView.setText(getTotalPriceString());
    FormatStringAndText.setPriceTextViewSize(mTotalPrice, BotequimActivity.mTotalPriceTextView);
}

private final TextWatcher priceTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        if (count != 0) {
            if (FormatStringAndText.isNumeric(s.toString())) {
                mProductPriceBeforeChange = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


        Toast.makeText(mContext, "posicao =" + posicaoGlobal, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (s.toString().length() == 0) {
            updateTotalPrice(posicaoGlobal, "0.00");
        } else {
            if (!isAutoCompleteClicked) {
                if (FormatStringAndText.isNumeric(s.toString())) {
                    mProductPriceAfterChange = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());BotequimActivity.mTotalPriceTextView.setText(getTotalPriceString());
                    //                  FormatStringAndText.setPriceTextViewSize(mTotalPrice, BotequimActivity.mTotalPriceTextView);
                    updateTotalPrice(posicaoGlobal, s.toString());
                } else {
                }

            } else {
                isAutoCompleteClicked = false;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


    }
};


public Double getTotalPrice(ArrayList<Product> productList, Double percent) {
    mTotalPrice = 0;
    for (Product product : productList) {
        mTotalPrice = mTotalPrice + percent * (product.getUnits() * (product.getDoublePrice()) / product.getDividedBy());
    }
    return mTotalPrice;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I had to call `priceTextWatcher` as an argument with it's constructor, just like `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()`. The correct one is:

```
 holder.mConsumablePriceTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
//...
}
//...methods inside here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the position when you create the TextWatcher.  I would do this with an inner subclass:

```
    // this is an inner class so it will have an implicit reference to
    // the adapter (ConsumableAdapter.this)  
    public class PriceTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        private int mPos;

        public PriceTextWatcher(int position) {
            super();
            mPos = position;
        }

        // now add your TextWatcher implementation here and use mPos for position

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

    }
```

Now you can initialize the position when you create the TextWatcher:

```
       holder.mConsumablePriceTextView.addTextChangedListener(new PriceTextWatcher(posicao));
```

You will have multiple TextWatchers instead of the single final TextWatcher you currently have, but that's the trade-off for getting the position value where it needs to be.